# VueJS is removing my !important CSS declaration

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2

I need to place inline !important css declarations in an **e-mail signature**, otherwise Gmail won't display it correct it.

My styles are binded via :style, and if I place !important in the declaration it removes that property.

```
...
linkStyle: {
     "textDecoration": "none !important", //this gets autoremoved
     "color": "#334593"
}
...
<a :style="linkStyle"></a>
...
```

Only the color gets applied, I've even tried this:

```
...
<a :style="linkStyle" style="text-decoration !important"></a>
...
```

To try and fool it, and it does get `text-decoration:none` applied but without the `!important flag`.

I'm lost. Can anybody tell me a workaround this?

Comment: Apply a class and put the `!important` in the css associated with the class.
https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3761#issuecomment-249422167

Comment: Will this style be inlined? Remember, e-mail signatures only deal with inline styling. I cannot have a <style> element.

Comment: Is this an option for you? `<a style="text-decoration:none !important"></a>`

Comment: Yes it was, I was a little sleep deprived and couldn't see my obvious syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some time I've found out that you have to use "text-decoration" instead to work:

```
linkStyle: {
    'text-decoration': 'none !important',
    color: "#334593"
}
```

In **vue.common.js** it reaches this line:

```
el.style.setProperty(name, val.replace(importantRE, ''), 'important');
```

Where `name = textDecoration`. In this case, the string `textDecoration` doesn't work, should be `text-decoration`.

Comment: Your answer is great because it takes a peek at how Vue actually parses it, and of course, the source code would reveal the mistery! That's why I'll give the checkmark to you instead of Roy, even though his answer is stellar too.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't include `textDecoration` in `linkStyle`, your last example works:

```js
const v = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    linkStyle: {
      color: "#334593"
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    document.getElementById('content').textContent = this.$el.innerHTML;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none !important" :style="linkStyle">Whatever</a>
</div>
<code id="content">
</code>
```

Comment: I think I might need some sleep, I've just now seen that I put `text-decoration !important` instead of `text-decoration: none !important`. I believe both your answer and Felippe's are great for different reasons.